# File path link opens in browser

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created a macro in excel to generate an email in MS Outlook. The contents of the email include hyperlinks to paths to file servers and network drives.

I am having a problem when the link has an ip address (e.g. 10.72.144.73, etc.).
There is no problem when the mail is generated in Outlook. I can open the path just fine. However, when the mail is sent and opened by the receiver, the link will open on the internet browser instead.

Here is the code so far. It is being formatted in HTML:

```
linkPath = Replace(linePath, " ", "%20")

strbody1 = "<font face=Calibri>Good day! <br><br>" & _
          "The following QA item/s have been added to <b>" & bookName & "</b> file." & _
          " Kindly confirm. Thank you very much. <br/>" & _
          "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <b>PATH:</b> <a href = " & linkPath & ">" & linePath & "</a><br>"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this all internal? If so, why aren't you using UNC paths?  If not, what do you expect them to open in if *not* the browser?

Comment: What does the `linkPath` actually look like? Does it begin with `file`? Is it a valid UNC path? Also, you may not be able to control how the recipient's email program handles hyperlinks, or what default programs they have associated with hyperlinks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths

Comment: Thanks! I reviewed the linked docs and arrived to a similar solution in the answer below. I also added a `file///` tag in order to force it to be recognized as a hyperlink to file/folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put "\\" at the first of address and try it again.

```
<a href = \\" & linkPath & ">
```